# Use local .git credential to commit code in remote project .git repository from vsCode

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code

I connect from my local vsCode window machine via Remote-SSh to Linux server which has git installed.
Is there any way which I use my local git credential to commit code inside my remote project?
my remote projects are inside a docker container and the reason why I need to follow this step is to don't copy my private key in different containers.
beside, i dont want to generate public key for each containers, it can be many containers which assigned to same developer and will be none sense to have different public keys for same developer.
other option is to copy public and private key of each developer to containers they use, and regarding security, i dont wanna use it.
any idea?

Comment: Is the git repository private? can you create a ssh key from linux machine and add it into the repository?

Comment: I know this might not be what you are looking for, but what you can do is download the updated project locally using `scp` and commit it from your machine.

Comment: @Andrea , ofcourse i can create key from Linux machine and add in repo, but the issue is, Linux machine is container and may be 100 of it , i dont want to make it for each developer manually.

Comment: @isea I have a similar situation in which I created 1 key for each machine, then I download the code in the phisical host and create container from there, without having to use keys in the containers